# SQL Server timing out without locking

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I have a server with 2 databases. Database X gets hit with several select statements from 7:30-8:30 AM.  Database Y gets hit every 5 minutes 24/7 with small insert/update statement.

The server times out on the insert/update statements on Database Y at around 7:30-8:30AM when Database X is getting hit by several select statements.

Is this a plausible case scenario? Even if the CPU is at 99% because of Database X's select statements, shouldn't the server be able to handle the insert/update statements on Database Y as 2 different databases means there is no locking involved? What can I do to debug this issue properly?

I'm sorry about the lack of details here, this is all I have so far. The error is the classic `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Comment: If CPU is at 99%, then doesnt have the time to complete the insert and give you time out. What else would you expect? Increase the timeout or add more CPU. Of course checking index of the select statement also should help. Unless you are amazon a few selects shouldn't take 99% of the CPU.

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza. I guess you're right. I was hoping the OS would still be able to handle the task in parallel even if the CPU was at 99% for some reason

Comment: Well I **hope** date Katy Perry some day, but isn't looking good neither :P There is a limit on what CPU can do after that you have to add more resources. But again use EXPLAIN PLAN to check query performance. You can post a different question and we can try to help optimize those